# JIRA REST API POST call via cURL with OAuth access token returns 401

Tags: php, curl, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

I have went through steps of getting an access token ( i did this though a terminal using java)
When i try to use a GET request in terminal with java like this:

```
java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar request ACCESS_TOKEN http://locahost:8015/rest/api/2/issue/TP-113
```

It works and returns an Issue JSON
But when i try to GET or POST an ISSUE using PHP and cURL like this

```
$FieldSummary = substr($items[0]->summary,strpos($items[0]->summary,'- ')+2);

    $FieldDescription = substr($items[0]->description,0);
    $FieldStartTime = new DateTime($items[0]->start->dateTime);
    $FieldEndTime = new DateTime($items[0]->end->dateTime);

    $dateStart = $FieldStartTime->format("Y-m-d\Th:m:s.sOZ");
    $dateEnd = $FieldEndTime->format("Y-m-d\Th:m:s.sOZ");


    $url = "http://".$config['jiraAdress']."/rest/api/2/issue/".$FieldKey;
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $headers = array(
      'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $data = json_encode ( array (
    'fields' => array (
            'summary' => $FieldSummary,
            'description' => $FieldDescription,
            'customfield_10007' => $dateStart,
            'customfield_10008' => $dateEnd 
    ) 
), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It returns error 401 and error JSON:

```
{
  "errorMessages": [
    "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.",
    "Login Required"
  ],
  "errors": {

  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Remember that this is JIRA REST API.

Comment: 1 obvious bug is that you dont escape the variables for the json, what do you think would happen if $FieldDescription contains 1 `"`? you should rewrite that to use json_encode. but that probably aint why you're getting the 401 error (because then it should respond `400 Bad Request`, not 401).

Comment: It works when I use Basic authentication, the problem is with using the OAuth token. Probably i am not providing all required headers. The fields can't be empty, and if it is it will write empty to the corresponding JIRA field.

Comment: but still, your json encoding is unreliable, and only works as long as the variables doesn't contain any characters with special meaning in javascript, because you're not escaping any potential special characters. do it like this instead: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/944275834d984e4fb0f1fd45d8d055e2

Comment: Okay, I edited the post with your suggestion.

Comment: oh, a little typo, got a big D in description, sorry